# Custom metadata for elasticsearch documents

Tags: search, elasticsearch, metadata

I was wandering what is the best way to add custom metadata for documents in elasticsearch.

Lets say I have a document of type `Test`

```
    "Test": {
                "properties": {
                   "TestName": {
                      "type": "string"
                   },
                   "LastRunTime": {
                      "type": "string"
                   },
                   "id": {
                      "type": "string"
                   },
                   "lastUpdate": {
                      "type": "string"
                   }   
                   ....         
}
```

And I would like to add for each field name - a display name. e.g.

```
                      "TestName": {
                          "type": "string"
                           "display_name": "Test Name"
                       },
                       "LastRunTime": {
                          "type": "string"
                           "display_name": "Last Run Time"
                       }
```

What is the best way to do it?
I know there's a field called `_meta` in an index mapping, is this the way to go?
I would also love if this metadata could be returned in each search query I perform on that index.

Comment: The _meta portion of the index mapping appears to be the only approach. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html. That is not returned in the results of a search.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to just use another field. It doesn't have to be [indexed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html). It's simpler and you can use `_source` filtering to retrieve or ignore it.